# How to read pkcs#7 file properly

Tags: c++, io, cryptoapi, pkcs#7

I have a file with detached pkcs#7 signature of size 267 bytes. I create it after executing

```
CryptSignMessage(
    &SigParams,
    TRUE,
    1,
    MessageArray,
    MessageSizeArray,
    pbSignedMessageBlob,
    &cbSignedMessageBlob)
```

function and then I write content of pbSignedMessageBlob:

```
pbSignedMessageBlob[cbSignedMessageBlob] = '\0';
 FILE *file;
 file = fopen("c:\\path\\sign_pkcs7.pk7", "wb");
 fwrite(pbSignedMessageBlob, sizeof(BYTE), cbSignedMessageBlob, file);
 fclose(file);
```

Then I try to verify this signature and read this file:

```
BYTE *pkcsContent;
FILE *file3;
file3 = fopen("c:\\users\\timur\\desktop\\sign_pkcs7.pk7", "rb");
pkcsContent = MyReadFile(file3, cbArray);
BYTE* MyReadFile(FILE *f, DWORD &len)
{
    size_t result;
    BYTE *buffer;
    if (f == NULL) 
    {
        fputs ("File error", stderr); 
        exit (1);
    }

fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
len = ftell (f);
rewind (f);

//buffer = (BYTE*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
buffer = new BYTE[len + 1];
if (buffer == NULL) 
{
    fputs ("Memory error", stderr); 
    exit (2);
}

result = fread (buffer, 1, len, f);
if (result != len) 
{
    fputs ("Reading error",stderr); 
    exit (3);
}
buffer[len] = '\0';

fclose (f);

    return buffer;
}
```

But the file content I get into pkcsContent is only 37 bytes length.
I also tried to manage files using std::fstream, but result is the same. Maybe the way I'm writing file to disk is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compute the length of `pkcsContent` with `strlen` (this is my guess since you're null-terminating the buffer in `MyReadFil`)? You can't do that because PKCS#7 is binary data and it can contain 0 anywhere.

Comment: Yes, strlen returns 37. But anyway, while debugging the content of the file and content of the variable where I read this file are completely different, hence I can't verify signature.

Comment: Actually, content of the variable is a truncated version of the file. File: [link](http://i39.tinypic.com/1zbuj2u.jpg) Variable: [link](http://i39.tinypic.com/2isthdw.png)